# I tried to solving this it became 4th power of equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

[image: this is my solution.its a long so i think its have antother process]Kindly see this image and solve it.

[image]

I solved this. But it form fourth power of equation. It is a 10th grade math. It seems any other techniq ond logic will apply please solve it. I didn't sleep whole night for this question

Comment: Yes and the solution isn't super nice: https://imgur.com/n1vRVvU

Comment: I outsourced it to Wolfram Alpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28x%2F%281-x%29%29%2Bsqrt%281-x%29%3D3%2F2

Comment: Can you describe any other method because it a tenth grade math..kindly solve this please..i also found the answer by forthpower of equation

Comment: Please at least show what you've tried. And the solution is never going to be all that nice with sums of square roots.

Comment: What is $2\frac12$, please clarify

Answer (score 2):

I am going to prove that the only real solution of the equation:

$\sqrt\frac{x}{1-x}+\sqrt{1-x}=1$

is $x=0$.

Proof:

It is necessary that $x\in\left[0,1\right[$ in order that the values inside the two square roots are nonnegative.

Squaring both sides of the equation, we obtain:

$\frac{x}{1-x}+1-x+2\sqrt{x}=1$

$\frac{x}{1-x}-x+2\sqrt{x}=0$

$\frac{x-x+x^2}{1-x}+2\sqrt{x}=0$

$\frac{x^2}{1-x}+2\sqrt{x}=0$

But $\frac{x^2}{1-x}\ge0$ and $2\sqrt{x}\ge0$, so there is only a possibility which is:

$\frac{x^2}{1-x}=2\sqrt{x}=0$

Therefore $x=0$.

As a matter of fact $x=0$ is a real solution of the equation and it is actually the only one.

Comment: So you're interpreting $2\frac12$ as $2\times\frac12$?

Comment: You mean the only *real* solution, others are complex, right?

Comment: Is $2\frac{1}{2}$ egual to $\frac{5}{2}$ ?

Comment: @Angelo Oh wait I wrote $3/2$ in WA for some reason but it shouldn't be much nicer with $5/2$

Comment: I think we should interpret $2\frac{1}{2}$ as $2\cdot\frac{1}{2}$ otherwise the solutions are not very nice especially for a tenth grade.

Comment: I think the question is miss printed by publishers.in denomineter there will be sqrt{x} then it will be a tenth grade question